# Origin of the constant $\phi$ in Binet's formula of the $n$-th term of the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I have read in a page that " To find the nth term of the Fibonacci series, we can use [Binet's Formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)"

> > F(n) = round( (Phi ^ n) / √5 ) provided n ≥ 0
> >     where Phi=1·61803 39887 49894 84820 45868 34365 63811 77203 09179 80576 ... .

my question is,

- What is this Phi?
- How they generated this Phi?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a very important constant in nature called the golden ratio, it appears in many different guises.

Binets formula is:

$F_n = \frac{(\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n})}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^n - (1-\sqrt{5})^n}{2^n \sqrt{5}}$

There are many different ways to prove Binet's formula. One I like in particular (which generalises to other linear difference equations) is to use eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a particular matrix. This is essentially the reason behind the appearance of $\phi$.

See here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 2):

The $\varphi$ here is the famous [Golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). It appears to be one of those fundamental numbers that arises from the nature itself. The Wikipedia link above provides a good discussion about its nature and its occurences in math.

As for its particular connection to the Fibonacci numbers, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) again gives a good explanation. (From a philosophical perspective, I would actually say that Fibonacci numbers are more fundamental than $\varphi$, but this is just a personal feeling...)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of generating $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}= 1.618$, and one of them is presented in Professor Strang's book [Introduction to Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232775). I'm modifying a bit the details, but the idea is what counts:

In the Fibonacci series, the recursive formula is such that it can be expressed as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}\\F_{n}\end{bmatrix}=\color{orange}{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}\begin{bmatrix}F_{n}\\F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

Starting at $u_0=\begin{bmatrix}F_1\\F_0\end{bmatrix}=\color{brown}{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}}$, we can proceed as

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_2\\F_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

and matrix multiply $100$ times to get $F_{100}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_{101}\\\color{blue}{F_{100}}\end{bmatrix}=\color{orange}{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}^{\color{blue}{100}}\color{brown}{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}}$$

which is straightforward if we can [eigendecompose the matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) $\color{orange}{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$:

$$\color{orange}{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}=S\Lambda S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\vert&\vert\\\text{ev}_1&\text{ev}_2\\\vert&\vert\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\vert&\vert\\\text{ev}_1&\text{ev}_2\\\vert&\vert\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

In which case:

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_{101}\\\color{blue}{F_{100}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\vert&\vert\\\text{ev}_1&\text{ev}_2\\\vert&\vert\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}^{\color{blue}{100}}\begin{bmatrix}\vert&\vert\\\text{ev}_1&\text{ev}_2\\\vert&\vert\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\color{brown}{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}}\tag 1$$

So we have to find the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$:

$$0=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}-\lambda\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&1\\1&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for the eigenvalues results in $\large\color{red}{\lambda_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ and $\large\lambda_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

**So we have "generated" the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) as the first eigenvalue of the matrix expressing the transformation from each column vector containing two adjacent Fibonacci numbers to to the next overlapping ordered pair.**

Here is the plot in relation to the basis vectors in the transformation $\small\begin{bmatrix}\color{orange}{1}&\color{red}{1}\\\color{orange}{1}&\color{red}{0}\end{bmatrix}:$

[image]

Just to wrap up the story, the eigenvectors are:

$\text{ev}_1=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\text{ev}_2=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

and going back to Eq.1:

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_{101}\\\color{blue}{F_{100}}\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\lambda_2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^{100}&0\\0&\lambda_2^{100}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-\lambda_2&\lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

and since $\lambda_2^{100}\simeq 0,$

$$\begin{bmatrix}F_{101}\\\color{blue}{F_{100}}\end{bmatrix}\simeq\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\lambda_2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^{100}\\0\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1^{101}\\\lambda_1^{100}\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$F_{100}\simeq\frac{\lambda_1^{100}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{100}$$

which is the approximation in the OP:

$$\color{blue}{F_n\simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio.
It is explain how you can calculate the $n^{th}$ term and give a method to calculate $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function):

\begin{align}
\color{brown}{f(x) = \sum_0^\infty F_n x^n} &= F_0x^0 + F_1x^1+F_2 x^2 + F_3 x^3+ F_4 x^4+\cdots\\
xf(x) &=  \quad\quad\quad\,  F_0x^1+F_1x^2+F_2x^3+F_3x^4+\cdots\\
x^2f(x)&=\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,F_0x^2+F_1x^3 + F_2x^4+\cdots
\end{align}

Since the value of $F_0=0$ and $F_1=F_2=1$, while the recursive formula is $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$,

\begin{align}
f(x)  &= F_1x^1+F_2 x^2 + F_3 x^3+ F_4 x^4+\cdots\\
-\big[ xf(x) &=  \quad\quad\quad\,  F_1x^2+F_2x^3+F_3x^4+\cdots\big]\\
-\big[x^2f(x)&=\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,F_1x^3 + F_2x^4+\cdots\big]\\
\quad\\
&\hline\\
(1-x-x^2)f(x)&=x\\
f(x)&=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
\end{align}

The denominator is a quadratic with roots $0=1-x-x^2$; $\large x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{-2}$, or $-\phi$ and $-\psi:$

$$\color{red}{\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} \text{ and } \psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
(1-x-x^2)f(x)&=x\\
f(x)&=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\\
f(x)&=\frac{-x}{(x+\varphi)(x-\psi)}\\
f(x)&=\frac{A}{x+\varphi}+\frac{B}{x-\psi}\tag 1
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$-x=A(x-\psi)+B(x+\varphi)$$

If $x=-\varphi$, $A=-\frac{\varphi}{\sqrt{5}}$, and if $x=-\psi$, $B=\frac{\psi}{\sqrt{5}}.$ Going back to Eq. 1:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{\psi}{x+\psi}}-\color{red}{\frac{\varphi}{x+\varphi}}\right)\tag 2$$

Since $\varphi=-\frac{1}{\psi}$,

$$\color{blue}{\frac{\psi}{x+\psi}}= \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{\psi}}
=\frac{1}{1-\varphi x}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varphi^n x^n\tag{*}
$$

(*) using the formula for the geometric series, $\sum_0^\infty x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}.$ In the case of

$$\color{red}{\frac{\varphi}{x+\varphi}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \psi^n x^n$$

Going back to Eq.2,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varphi^n x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \psi^n x^n\right)=\sum_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \varphi^n - \psi^n \right)x^n=\color{brown}{\sum_0^\infty F_n x^n}$$

So we get [Binet's formula](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula):

$$\large F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\varphi^n-\psi^n)\tag{Binet's formula}$$